# Why does %in% compare the data type while, == can compare strings?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a rather basic question. Can someone explain to me why the former works, while the latter does not and why the Date data type matters?

```
library(data.table)

test.table <- data.table(Dates = 
                           as.Date(c("2020-08-31", "2020-01-31", "2020-08-31", "2010-01-01")))

test.table[Dates == "2020-08-31"]

test.table[Dates %in% c("2020-08-31")]
```

Comment: I think this is unrelated to `data.table` and that the answer is to be found in `?'=='` and `?'%in%'` in the parts the discuss coercion.

Comment: `%in%` can show flexibility too: `TRUE %in% 1` gives `TRUE`

Answer (score 3):

This is not specific to data.table. The documentation in `help("%in%)` says this:

> Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, and then x and table are coerced to a common type (the later of the two types in R's ordering, logical < integer < numeric < complex < character) before matching.

The common type between a Date variable and a character variable is "character". Since the documentation refers to types and not to classes, `as.character.Date` is not involved. I assume the internal doubles of the Date variable are coerced and compared.

You should never rely on the automatic coercion for comparisons. Always use explicit coercion:

```
Dates %in% as.Date("2020-08-31")

Dates == as.Date("2020-08-31")
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding

```r
test.table[Dates %in% c("2020-08-31")]
```

`c("2020-08-31")` is treated as a character class while `test.table$Dates` is a Date class. Therefore, they are not a match when using `%in%`.

If you convert the `Dates` as character or `c("2020-08-31")` as Date, you will get the same match.

```r
test.table[as.character(Dates) %in% c("2020-08-31")]

test.table[Dates %in% as.Date("2020-08-31")]
```